# Post upload multipart/form-data query?

Tags: php, android

Must the file pass through this no matter what? Still stuck on uploading an image from an Android phone that does not come out as an application/octet type and as image/JPEG type.

Comment: when you say you're 'stuck' what have you actually tried?

Comment: Do I have to pass a file(image) through a forms upload multipart/form-data before using my upload.php to add to mysql database which works fine but stores as a application/octet type rather than Image type.